# How to allow user to insert grammatical equation with checking some rule in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html, grammar

I dont want evaluation. I want validation of equatioin at html side.

I want to allow user to enter this type equation in textbox with validation:

```
400 - IF(age > 32, 6, 4) +10
```

where age is fix string, there will be other fix string lile weight, birthdate etc....

So is there way to validate this custom equation as user enter text,

Is there any jquery plugin?

I know  here IF() is custom equation, so i must have to make custom cset of rule.

I just want some suggestion or plugin that how can i do it?

Any help would be helpful for me.

Comment: Do you mean `eval()`?

Comment: @doveyg  Just validation from html side.

Comment: In that case you want some rather complex regex. What have you tried? post examples and [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Make a parser. [PEG.js](http://pegjs.org/) is good.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the variables as actual variables and then do an `eval` call on the string from the input- like so:

```
var age = 10;
eval("20-age"); // returns 10
```

Note that dependending on what you're going to use this for, this might be a real security risk and if you're going to save the input anywhere you'd obviously need to validate and sanitize the input on the server side.

Comment: Sure. Textbook scriping vulnerability.

Comment: Whats the worse you can do? Javascript is client side, The user wont be able to effect anything server side.

Comment: Well, it is. But it really depends on what the expression is going to be used for. The question actually want's to execute a user defined expression and I'm not sure how you'd achieve that if not going with an approach like this

Comment: @doveyg: "What's the worse you can do?" As a trivial example, say you allow sharing of expressions with other users; the expression could be stored on a server, and evaluated by someone else. Then an attacker could craft an expression that would steal private information (CSRF token or something) and send it to the attacker's drop. Maybe OP's app won't allow for something like that; maybe it does. Are you a gambler?

Comment: @sebbzzz: "How you'd achieve that" - as I said in question comments, and as expressions are normally evaluated by any programming language: you make a parser. Your answer is okay now with the disclaimer added; if OP decides the security cannot be compromised, it's fine.

Comment: @Amadan: If its going into a database, I would assume the protection/validation would lie at that level. Prevent users from inputting malicious code.